# how to run SmartStore.NET in localpc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, nopcommerce

How do I start smartstore.net in Visual Studio localhost?

I downloaded the GitHub code and opened project file from SmartStoreNET-2.x\src\SmartStoreNET.sln

The download link is:
https://github.com/liuzengjun/smartstore

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here some steps for build project

1.open you project/solution in visual studio 13 or you can use visual studio 12 but make sure that it must be fully updated because solution uses the latest version of mvc and all other controls.

2.build SmartStore.Web.Framework.

3.build SmartStore.Web

4.build SmartStore.Services

5.build SmartStore.Data

6.build SmartStore.Core

7.build SmartStore.Admin

after build all the solutions keep SmartStore.Web start as project and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Today you can run Smartstore in the cloud if you like. Try it here with a free Azure account.

https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/smartstore-ag.smartstorenet